Enterprise internal VS Code Extensions Reposotory
I work in a company that has few VS Code extensions that relevant only for that company and cannot be published to the publish VS Code Marketplace.
Is there a way to set VS Code to look at another "private marketplace" for extensions?

I've found https://coder.com/blog/running-a-private-vs-code-extension-marketplace which suggest a way to do it but it seems not supported officially by Microsoft VS Code

There's an open feature request on GitHub for exactly this. There are a few comments presenting a few different options but as yet, no offical support and the request has been open since 2017!

Tool recommendation is off topic on this site. The GitHub thread has all commercial/free options and it's up to your own evaluation to decide either adopting one of them or develop your own.
